# shell_exec() always returning an empty string

Tags: php, linux, apache, terminal, server

I am trying to create a server within my Android phone. I am unable to execute any shell script from my PHP code.

Here's the code:

```
//index.php
<?php
$output=shell_exec("sdcard/htdocs/myscript.sh 2>&1");
if(!$output){
  echo "Failed";
}else{
  echo $output;
}
?>

//myscript.sh
cd sdcard/htdocs/images
ls -t1 | head -n 1
```

The script works fine within terminal emulator. I also tried changing permissions of the script file but that didn't work. I don't know if it requires superuser permissions to execute shell scripts within PHP code.

The whole code is used to return the filename of the last file created in the images directory.

Need suggestions to make this code work.Is there any other way to perform the required job?

Comment: Is `shell_exec()` enabled in your PHP config?

Comment: safe mode is Off and there is nothing to the right of disable_functions in php.ini

Comment: You may want to try another program execution function that provides more diagnostics such as [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). However, your relative path suggests the script is hosted at `/mnt` or a similar location, which is a strange place to put scripts... I bet it's just not finding the script because the path is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Superuser permission is not necessary for script execution. You should turn on PHP error output or check the PHP error log file. I bet you find the reason there. If not, recheck the directory, and file permissions:

```
./index.php
./sdcard/htdocs/myscript.sh
./sdcard/htdocs/images
```

`sdcard` and `sdcard/htdocs` require executable persmissions. `sdcard/htdocs/images` requires executable and read permission (`ls` in `myscript.sh`), and so does `sdcard/htdocs/myscript.sh`. But I guess it's something else because permission errors should be displayed (`2>&1`).

---

**Edit**

You can find the last modified file with PHP, no need to run another process. Take one of these two:

```
$images = glob('sdcard/htdocs/images/*');
$images = array_combine(array_map('filemtime', $images), $images);
asort($images);
echo $lastModifiedImage = end($images);
```

Or with some fewer array operations:

```
$images = glob('sdcard/htdocs/images/*');
array_reduce($images, function($previous, $element) use (&$found) {
    $mtime = filemtime($element);
    $found = $previous < $mtime ? $found : $element;
    return $previous < $mtime ? $mtime : $previous;
}, 0);
echo $found;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure what you have run

`chmod a+x sdcard/htdocs/myscript.sh`

on your file.

Also $output is not a boolean.

Answer (score -1):

sdcard and sdcard/htdocs require executable persmissions. sdcard/htdocs/images requires executable and read permission (ls in myscript.sh), and so does sdcard/htdocs/myscript.sh. But I guess it's something else because permission errors should be displayed (2>&1).

Probably FAT !

Comment: This should probably be a comment, since you aren't answering the question.